# Hide text after first line break? (not <br />, but wrapped by the browser)

Tags: jquery, css, line-breaks

Is it somehow possible to know where the text is split and a new line is started and hide everything after the first line, either with css or with js?

So if I have the following text displayed in the browser

```
 aaa aaa aaa aaa 
 bbb bbb bbb bbb
```

Only the first line should be displayed.

Note that the second line is started because of the width of the div container, not because of using `<br />` or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with CSS.

```
#content {
    height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See [example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MED62/1/)

Comment: The height of the container is random, it could be 20px, 50px, etc.  Your solution would show partial text (top half) in several cases.

Comment: @Wesley Not with the `em` unit. 1em is equal to the current font size. I can increase the font size and it still works. http://jsfiddle.net/MED62/2/

Comment: Only 1 problem @Peter Of The Corn - If I add padding it starts displaying portions of text again. Can't use margin as the container has a bg color.

Comment: @Wesley If you want to avoid complicated javascript calculations, you could put the content inside a containing element and apply padding to it. http://jsfiddle.net/MED62/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/92073.php

```
<div style="line-height:15px;height:16px;overflow:hidden;"> 
 aaa aaa aaa aaa <br /> 
 bbb bbb bbb bbb 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on @Peter's answer:

```
#content .wrapper-for-text {
  display:inline-block;
  height:1em;
  overflow-hidden;
}
```

Working example, including padding on the wrapper, here: http://jsfiddle.net/MED62/4/

Comment: What's the advantage of span with inline-block @Phrogz ? Several (old) browsers don't support it, if I were to just use a div wouldn't that be better overall?

Comment: @Wesley Assuming that your wrapping element is block level (and hence syntactically valid to have a `<div>` as a child) then yes, a `<div>` would be compatible with a small percentage more users. If your wrapping element does not allow certain block-level children (e.g. if this was inside an `<a>` element) then it would be invalid to have a `<div>` as a child.